# plotfly cufflinks doesnt create a plot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, data-visualization, data-science

Would anyone be able to give me a tip on plotting a pandas dataframe (Jupyter lab 3.7) with plotly/cufflinks offline? When I run the code there isnt a plot that shows up, no errors or anything.. Just blank cell

```
#importing plotly and cufflinks in offline mode
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
cf.go_offline()
cf.set_config_file(offline=False, world_readable=True)
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

allDat.iplot()
```

This is a screenshot of the pandas dataframe that I called `allDat` that I am attempting to just make a simple line plot of everything

[image]

Comment: Can you try to create a simple Plotly figure in your notebook? Your code should work fine, seems the problem is somewere else. Also try `allDat = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(1, 5)})` to check if your data frame has something weird in it.

Comment: If use `pd.DataFrame({'a': range(1, 5)})` nothing happens either.. The dataframe is created properly but when I run `iplot() nothing happens. No errors either

Comment: This is time series data.. When I use matplotlib it works but I get a warning, `Using an implicitly registered datetime converter for a matplotlib plotting method. The converter was registered by pandas on import. Future versions of pandas will require you to explicitly register matplotlib converters.`

Comment: And also: `To register the converters:
 >>> from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
 >>> register_matplotlib_converters()`

Comment: Can I use cufflinks for this? Thanks for your help